# Site Edit content showing in Chrome and FireFox but NOT in IE

Tags: 2011, siteedit

We have a site in SDL Tridion 2011 with SiteEdit enabled. For this We are able to edit content in Chrome and FireFox but not in IE. Refer images below.
[image]

Comment: What makes it specific to SiteEdit? It looks like your site is simply not showing the proper content in IE (probably a CSS issue or a problem with the markup). Unless you're saying that the content somehow vanishes as soon as you click on the SiteEdit button?

Comment: More details are needed. What is the version of Site Edit? What is the version of IE? is it Site Edit or Tridion GUI?

Comment: Peter - Actually these are two tabs "Overview" and Performance". For the  "Performance" tab the content does not show up during Site Edit. I have checked and the tags are all in place.  Pankaj - Its is in IE9 and yes it is the SiteEdit UI.

Comment: I would suggest then to edit your question and let it reflect the "Tridion UI" instead of Site Edit. There is nothing called as SiteEdit UI :)

Comment: Pankaj - yes the Tridion UI for Site Edit.

Answer (score 2):

If it is SiteEdit 2009 SP3, then apply following Hot Fix: [SE_2.3.0.76375 - Cumulative Hotfix](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SiteEdit_2009_SP3/index.aspx) and try again.

If it is SiteEdir 2009 SP2, then apply following Hot Fix: [SE_2.2.0.83094 - Cumulative hotfix](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SiteEdit_2009_SP2/index.aspx) and try again.

Hopefully it should resolve the issue.

Comment: from screenshot it seems UI-2012 not SE

Comment: never seen UI 2012 or anything after Site Edit 2009...so not sure. XPM is the next big thing